# Access a system URL in the network

Tags: windows-server-2008, tomcat6

I am trying to access the url `localhost:8088/openbravo`  from the network. The local IP of the system is `192.168.1.101/openbravo`.  But when i try it from other system in the network, it doesn't work. Is there any setting that i need to do.

i added the ip address in the `hosts` file of the local system. But it didn't work too.

System is windows 2008 server 64bit.

--
Thanks

Comment: is other system in same network??

Comment: in the same network..   accessing from a system of ip 192.168.1.22

Comment: did u try with my answer, i posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With it being Server 2008, have you disabled the Windows Firewall to see if it will work. It may be blocking incoming connections from that port from the other local networked machine. After the test, then you can reenable and add a firewall exception for the tomcat port of 8088.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766337(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks a ton!  the incoming connections for that port was restricted. I added a rule to allow that port!!!

Answer (score 0):

try with this  192.168.1.101:8088/openbravo.

Comment: yes i tried with 192.168.1.101:8088/openbravo..  but still the browser couldnot connect.   I made changes in  tomcat  server.xml..  replacing localhost with the ipaddress of that system..